# probability- minimum and maximum value of a union

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference, intersection-theory

Suppose that events A and B exist such that P(A)=0.15, P(B)=0.2 . The maximum and minimum possible value for P(not A or not B)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! As this site is meant to be a useful repository rather than a Do My Homework forum, it's common courtesy to show what you've already tried, and really narrow down what you're struggling with. Most people here are glad to help once you've adequately motivated the problem. [Quick Guide](http://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34067/21813) to attracting answers and preventing your question from being deleted. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

By De Morgan's law, $A^c\cup B^c=(A\cap B)^c$.

With this, $\mathbb{P}(A^c\cup B^c)=\mathbb{P}((A\cap B)^c)=1-\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)$.

Because $0\leq \mathbb{P}(A\cap B)\leq \min\{\mathbb{P}(A),\mathbb{P}(B)\}=0.15$, we have

$0.85\leq\mathbb{P}(A^c\cup B^c)\leq 1$.

These values are reached when $A\subset B$ and $A\cap B=\emptyset$, respectively.